# C-Examining a specific memory adress during execution

Tags: c, pointers, heap-memory

Is it possible to dereference a void pointer without a cast knowing(during execution) the size of the item located in memory ? Or, if not possible with a void pointer, how can I access a specific memory address(located in the heap) and read an only-known during execution specific number of bytes ?

Comment: Use a `char *` or more technically correct a `uint8_t *`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With a `char *` which basically points to a byte size of memory you can access all the bytes of any datatype.

And you can also cast a `void *` to necessary type and deference it to get the correct dereferenced value.